# Wordwrap Win32

Tags: winapi, word-wrap

I'm trying to wordwrap a block of text for display in a window that would otherwise be too long. The font I'm using is not a fixed width font, so GetSystemMetrics will not return accurate values for my text.

Using a `static` window is not an option here because a `static` window doesn't tell me one crucial piece of information: The height of the text drawn after wordwrapping.

Any ideas?

Billy3

Comment: Since two answers were essentially the same I checked the earlier posted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Win32 API call [DrawtextEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162499(VS.85).aspx).  You'll need to pass the **DT_CALCRECT** option, telling Windows that you wish for the rectangle to be calculated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [*DrawText()*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498(VS.85).aspx) API function with the *DT_CALCRECT* flag set. You would need to select the correct font for the HDC first.

Answer (score 1):

`DrawTextEx()` will do everything you want and need if the entire text is to be displayed in a single font.

If you need to mix fonts, you'll have to do the work yourself.  In that case, you'll want to look at APIs like `GetTextMetrics()` (not `GetSystemMetrics()`) and `GetTextExtentExPoint32()` to figure out positions and sizes for each run.

If you need to handle complex scripts (e.g., right-to-left languages and scripts where the letters change shape depending on context), you'll need Uniscribe.  Caution:  Uniscribe is powerful but very low level.  It can take a lot of work to wrap it with a higher-level interface.  If you need complex script handling, you might be better off using a browser control.

Answer (score 0):

Both `DrawText()` and `DrawTextEx()` can accomplish that. The key is to use `DT_WORDBREAK` in the `format` parameter.

To draw text within a 100 x 100 rectangle at the top let, one could use either:

```
    RECT textRect;
    SetRect(&textRect, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    DrawText(hdc,TEXT("THIS IS TEXT THAT WILL PROBABLY WRAP AROUND A 100 BY 100 RECTANGLE. BUT YOU CAN'T BE SURE UNLESS YOU TRY."),-1,&textRect, DT_LEFT | DT_NOCLIP | DT_WORDBREAK);
```

The `DT_LEFT` option aligns the sentences to the left. The `DT_NOCLIP` ensures that text isn't cut out at the bottom.

OR

Use `DrawTextEx()`:

```
    RECT textRect;
    SetRect(&textRect, 0, 0, 100,100);
    DrawTextEx(hdc,(LPSTR)TEXT("THIS IS TEXT THAT WILL PROBABLY WRAP AROUND A 100 BY 100 RECTANGLE. BUT YOU CAN'T BE SURE UNLESS YOU TRY."), -1, &textRect, DT_LEFT| DT_NOCLIP|DT_WORDBREAK , NULL);
```